# Problems with my Intel HD GC

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics

I'm running Ubuntu and I have an Intel HD graphic card, I installed Counter Strike 1.6 and I cannot launch wide screen display mode, parts from the both side of my screen are black.
Also when I am playing some clips on YouTube, both sides on the screen are black and I don't see the whole picture.

When I click on "About this computer" I'm getting this:

- Intel® Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2

But I can't find the driver for my Intel GC. I have this driver installed:

- X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx

Comment: Just let you know that I have an Acer Aspire 5349...

Comment: add that to the post then! :)

Comment: I have been installed cs 1.6 on my detskop computer and I have the same problem which I solved, I adjusted horizontal size on 100 and the problem isnt now there, I must do the same thing on laptop, just tell me what must I type in my Terminal...

Comment: It looks like the problem is in my graphic card, on my computer I can change video option into widscreen, on my laptop I cant...

Comment: can u solve my problem or dont , if dont just tell me right now and I will get another Linux. Thanks...

Comment: So CS has a "widescreen" display mode, and you selected that, right? I'm sorry, I'm not sure if I can help, but I will try :)

Comment: No I cant select it it is grey , I have monitor with higher resolution then the cs 1.6 supports, meybe the problem is in it, I dont know, if I  knew I wouldnt be asking you...

Comment: Meybe I must to adjuste screen I dont know you tell me , you are an engineer...

Comment: I think it is something bad with the driver for intel hd, hahah, ubuntu almost dont have any driver, how it has driver if I cant launch that aplication......sorry , but HELP ME...

Comment: Sorry for talking personal things but my friend also has intel hd and he  is running with no black screen, my other friend who I dont talk with helped him, thats the reason Im asking you man, isnt my attention to bother...

Comment: Tell me what shall I type into the Terminal to open xorg options , now I cant open open gl, so tell what to type into Terminal to open video card driver options and to change it if I must....

Comment: OpenGL doesn't work? Try running this: `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils; glxgears` (first command installs software, so you will have to enter your passoword and press Y when prompted). See if a window pops up when running the second command. If not, could you send the output of the two commands in the post above?

Comment: mesa-utils is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 133 not upgraded.

Comment: 2563 frames in 5.0 seconds = 512.438 FPS
2554 frames in 5.0 seconds = 510.727 FPS
2076 frames in 5.0 seconds = 415.151 FPS
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0.0"
      after 192283 requests (192281 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
stevan@Stevan ~ $ ^C
stevan@Stevan ~ $ ^C
stevan@Stevan ~ $

Comment: Can I send u the pictures of my screen to see, just tell me how to send u....

Comment: the window pops up...

Comment: No need to send pictures, I know it works now :) Here is something that _might_ be the cause (not saying it is, just passing it as a possibility), it might be because you have a really low framerate that your problem is happening. How big is your screen?

Comment: 15.6 n it is big

Comment: Okay... hmm... what graphics card do you have? If you do not know, could you post the output of this command? `lspci -nn | grep '\[03..\]'`

Comment: shall I do something with the video card driver?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just want to know if the problem is because of your graphics card and ubuntu support or if it is because of a X.org/driver issue.

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0106] (rev 09)

Comment: oh yay, intel integrated graphics :/. What's your CPU? i3-i7? Or atom?

Comment: b815, it is intel b815

Comment: Okay, something to note... even if CS worked widescreen, your framerate would be _seriously_ low, so maybe that's why it's greyed out...

Comment: ok, I dont think so , Im still thinking that it is something with the driver...

Comment: you saw that in cs options there isnt higher resolution than 1280, whatever, maybe is of that reason greyed...

Comment: Oh wait a minute, I just re-read your question... that is because your screen is widescreen, and the applications/videos don't work widescreen (they work using 4:3, not 16:9). Sorry about the whole confusion there!

Comment: what now? is there a cure...?

Comment: my friend fixed that but I dont know how

Comment: If there is a widescreen option somewhere, select it, but if not, I don't think so. Sorry! It _might_ be possible to somehow stretch the display, but I don't think you want that.

Comment: In Counter Strike?

Comment: can we do some adjusting of size whatever, when I enter cs?

Comment: ok, then nothing, thanks for the time, bay bay, good night...

Comment: I presume it is possible... I do not have counter strike however. Here is what I found: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1189128

Comment: Or here: http://www.widescreengaming.net/wiki/Counter-Strike

Comment: ok , thanks a lot, to me is lefting only to see what my friend did, then I ll tell you, ok now Im leaving you, CAOOOOO :D THANKS...

Comment: Ok, hope you can fix it :D

Comment: @MiJyn - Please do not have a conversation though comments.  Post an answer and continually edit it with new information.  Thanks.

Comment: @StevanHranisavljevic - similar comment - please edit your question with new information - please do so now and delete your comments to tidy up this very long comment thread.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, the solution is this: you already have wine installed on your Linux, if you wouldnt have wine you wouldnt be playng cs, you must ran configure wine aplication, there you have some options, then run graphics, check emulate virtual desktop, then you set a resolution 16:9 example 1360 x 765, then run cs, run options , video, the display mode isnt anymore greyed, you can now change it from normal to widscreen, when you change that options you run resolution and now you have 1360 x 765 available, whatever you did put, dont put some resolution in the configure wine which is bigest then the resolution of your monitor, the resolution you put must be in order with 16:9 list resolutions, hope this was usefull for your cs playing, see you people on some cs server, and enjoy while you are playing cs....See you... Caooooo. Pozzzzzzzdrav. Pozzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz from Serbia...